# Map contains null value for a key but returns false when called from another method

Tags: apex, map, debugging

I'm using the following conditional logic in my class

```
if(mapCountry.get(rec.Country__c).Allowed__c != null)
```

The value of `mapCountry.get(rec.Country__c).Allowed__c` accessed via debug is false.

However the value of the map (also accessed via debug) is,

```
mapCountry:{Antigua and Barbuda=Country__c:{Allowed__c=null, Down__c=true}}
```

`Allowed__c` is a Boolean checkbbox. I'm trying to understand why the conditional statement used in a different function returns `false` while its supposed to return `null`, as per the map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Accessing SObject Fields](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SObjects_accessing_fields.htm) notes this interesting behavior

> An expression with SObject fields of type Boolean evaluates to true
> only if the SObject field is true. **If the field is false or null, the
> expression evaluates to false**

Their code example also demonstrates the behavior

```java
Campaign cObj= new Campaign(); 
...
if (cObj.IsActive == null) {
    ... // IsActive is evaluated to false and this code block is not executed.
}
```

So, in your case, when using dot notation to interact with the SObject field (`.Allowed__c`) you'll see it always evaluate to `true` or `false`.

Whereas, when debugging the map values themselves - you'll see the `null` value.

In terms of your code example, due to the behavior documented above with using SObject Fields directly, you'll have to utilize [SObject get(field)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm#apex_System_SObject_get_2) which will return `null`.

```java
if(mapCountry.get(rec.Country__c).get('Allowed__c') != null)
```

Comment: I think this is new behavior... that would simplify some of my code.

Comment: which part - object notation or the .get(field) behavior or both? The relevant section in the document about null/false seems to have been added in Winter '20, but I think that behavior had existed undocumented before (if I remember correctly).